# Share data between containers via volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a docker-compose, where I have 2 services:

1. static builder
2. nginx server

And also defined volume. /static directory from first and second container are mapped to this volume. Like this:
`- static_build:/static/`

So the first image Dockerfile looks roughly like this:

`FROM node
COPY src /app
RUN yarn build
CMD mv build /static`

If I use `CMD` in last line it works fine. During `docker-compose up` docker executes `mv build /static` and `build` appears in nginx container.

But if i use `RUN mv build /static` and `docker-compose up` files in shared directory doesn't change. Even if I add some basic `CMD` (like `CMD echo foo`) to ensure, that container was created and executed, shared directory has no changes.

I understand, that image is a collection of changes to the filesystem of base layer, but how docker manages situation when there are several containers to up and they have different content of directories shared between containers?